# How to set the block(chunk) size for a Google Cloud Store Bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am reading [this article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/optimizing-your-cloud-storage-performance-google-cloud-performance-atlas). It said "To demonstrate this, let’s take an 8MB file, and fetch it through different sized chunks. In the graph below, we can see that as the block size gets larger, performance improves. As the chunk size decreases, the overhead per-transaction increases, and performance slows down." in section "Set your optimal fetch size".

However, I try to check the Google Cloud Storage settings but there are no "block size", "chunk size" or "fetch size". Where is such a setting?

Answer (score 0):

A part of the answer is in the answer, this parameter

```
GSUtil:sliced_object_download_max_components=8
```

It allows you to download in a number of slice. In the given example, it is used on a 8Mb file and therefore you can deduce the size of each chunk. The size of the chunks aren't important in the article, but the HTTP overhead incurs: the more chunks you have, the more HTTP request you get, and therefore, the more HTTP overhead you pay (in time manner)

Comment: That option does not directly set the read chunk size. It sets the number of parts of an object to download separately in parallel. There is no option to set the read chunk size.

Comment: @JohnHanley why then is it written: "To demonstrate this, let’s take an 8MB file, and fetch it through different sized chunks. In the graph below, we can see that as the block size gets larger, performance improves. As the chunk size decreases, the overhead per-transaction increases, and performance slows down."

why would they write about a solution, without a possibility to actually implement it? faulty docs?

Comment: @tikej - TCP performance is very complex. Setting items like buffer sizes, overlapped requests, etc require a detailed analysis. In the real world, you will have a hard time tuning TCP performance beyond basic guidelines. The documentation is not faulty, it is just a simplification of a complex issue. To get started, study the TCP Nagle Algorithm which discusses TCP packet size. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm

Comment: @tikej Then you must study the OS tuning parameters which often override settings that an application attempts to control. 256 KB buffer size and four threads will provide 90+% possible performance. The speed and latency of the **last mile** of your Internet connection will have a significant effect on performance. Those parameters often change by the second because of other services/clients using the same network connection or fiber.